Stein's method for non-unit variance
Stein's method gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges in the Wasserstein metric to the standard gaussian if $X_i$ are independent and $\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]=1$.
Can the ideas of the Stein's method be applied if the variances are distinct? I know there's other variations such as a lyapanov's but I would eventually like to remove the independent assumption and use dependency neighbourhood idea from stein's.

Strictly speaking, Stein's method does not establish convergence, but only provides a bound on the difference between $W_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $X \sim N(0,1)$ in the Wasserstein metric. In the simplest case, if $X_i$ are independent with $\mathbb{E}X_i = 0$, $\mathbb{E}X_i^4 < \infty$, and $\mathbb{E}X_i^2 = 1$, then
$$
d_W(W_n, X) \leq \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}|X_i|^3 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi} n} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}X_i^4},
$$
as stated in, e.g., Theorem 3.2 in the Fundamentals of Stein's method by Ross. If the first sum is $o(n^{3/2})$ and the second is $o(n^2)$ as $n\to\infty$, then the convergence holds. For example, if $X_i$ are i.i.d., then these sums are $n\cdot\mathbb{E}|X_1|^3$ and $n\cdot\mathbb{E}X_1^4$, respectively, so $d_W(W_n, X) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ at the rate of $1/\sqrt{n}$.
If $Y_i$ are independent with $\mathbb{E}Y_i^4 < \infty$, the bound still holds for $X_i = \frac{Y_i - \mathbb{E}Y_i}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}Y_i^2}}$, and one can deduce conditions that imply $d_W(W_n, X) \to 0$.
However, in the case of dependency neighbourhoods, Theorem 3.6 in Ross' article provides a bound with no assumptions on variances of $X_i$:
$$
d_W(W_n, X) \leq \frac{D_n^2}{\sigma_n^3} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}|X_i|^3 + \frac{\sqrt{28} D_n^{3/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sigma_n^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}X_i^4},
$$
where $\mathbb{E}X_i = 0$, $\mathbb{E} X_i^4 < \infty$,
$\sigma_n^2 = \mathrm{var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)$,
$W_n = \frac{1}{\sigma_n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$, and $D_n = \max_{1\leq i \leq n} |N_i|$, where $N_i$ are the dependency neighbourhoods of $X_1, ..., X_n$. Convergence can be established under some conditions on the asymptotic behaviour of $\sigma_n$, $D_n$, and both sums.
